# centrar divs dentro de otro div

Tags: php, html, css, html5, css3

¿Cómo puedo centrar uno o varios `div` que están dentro de otro `div`(padre) y que se ajusten a la pantalla de cualquier dispositivo, ya sea computadora, tablet o teléfono celular?

Genero una lista de unas imágenes en mi BD y las muestro. Pero cuando abro el archivo desde un teléfono, todo se pone a la izquierda.

**Archivo CSS**

```
#imagelist {
    float: left;
    margin: 5px;
}

#caption {

    color: black;
    background-color: white;
    font-weight: bold;
    font-size: 15px;
}


/* 100% Image Width on Smaller Screens */
@media only screen and (max-width: 700px) {
    #imagelist{
        position : relative;
    }
    #card{
        left : 25%; 

    }
}
```

**Archivo PHP**

```
<div class="imgcontainer" >
<?php
include 'database_config6.php';

$result = $bd->query("SELECT * FROM usuarios");
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
    echo '<div id="imagelist" style="background-color: red;">';
    echo '
    <div class="card" id="card" style="width: 200px">
        <img class="card-img-top" src="' . $row['imageurl'] . '" alt="Card image cap">
        <div class="card-body">
        <p class="card-text" id="caption">' . $row['nombre'] ."&nbsp;". $row['apellidop']."&nbsp;".$row['apellidom'] . '</p>
        </div>
    </div>
    ';
    echo '</div>';
}
?>
</div>
```

Comment: Prueba a ponerle margin auto al elemento que quieras centrar

Comment: ¿Revisaste las demás preguntas en el sitio y ninguna respuesta te sirvió? Parece ser una duda que se repite muy a menudo sobre CSS: https://es.stackoverflow.com/search?q=centrar+div+css

Answer (score 2):

Primero asegúrate que el contenedor padre este alineado de manera horizontal en cuanto a los demás contenedores, para eso puedes utilizar `display:flex;`. A los demás ya no seria necesario aplicarles la propiedad `flex` ya que el contenedor padre la utiliza.

Si al elemento o los elementos que vas a alinear les colocaras otras clases dentro de un contenedor hijo, puede resultar enlazando con otras clases sin importar la primera propiedad, es decir al `child item, item:` es el hijo y se alineará al colocar el `display` dentro. Ejemplo:

```
  .imageList {
   display:flex;
   }

   .item {
   justify-content:center; //alinearlo horizontalmente
   align-items:center; alinea de manera vertical los elementos
  }
```

Adicionalmente agregas una animación y que termine justo cuando finaliza el contenedor padre.

Answer (score 2):

El div que quieres centrar, es decir el interior, le pones `margin: 0 auto; float:none` y listo